# Merging adjacent polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, layers, merge, adjacency

I have a set of polygon layers with thousands of polygons some of which are adjacent (Either rings or simply adjacent). I would like to simplify this polygons by merging them.

Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: Tried Processing Toolbox "Dissolve" followed by "Multipart to Singlepart" (if applies) Tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could ask the dissolve tool which you can select through the Vector tab, then Geoprocessing tools.

[image]

Then select the dissolve tool to open and input the dataset

[image]

You could also refer to [QGIS documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/shapes_polygons/polygondissolve.html)

Comment: Solution to my problem was "Dissolve" > "Dissolve all" followed by Multipart to Singlepart. The first step can take very long sometimes though. In the case of about 10000 polygons it can be about 4-5 hours. 

Maybe there is a faster solution?